# How to parallel unpickleable object processing?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, pickle

I use treesitter to parse source files.
Sometimes the source files are large enough to make treesitter "cry" for relatively long time.
I use treesitter bindings for python and the objects that I work with are Parser and Tree.
The problem with these objects is that they are unpickleables, thus making it impossible for me to offload the work to an async worker.

All I need is a way to call parser.parse() with the source file bytes from an async worker
and return the Tree object to the main thread. This seems like a trivial objective which I couldn't find a way to achieve.

If there were a synchronization challenge I could understand, but it seems to me that because python does not allow "true" parallel threads than I have to work with processes, which in turns transfer the challenge to communication, and with pickle not being able to communicate all kind of stuff, there is simply no way to achieve that... am I missing something?

I tries using the Queue and Pipe objects to communicate the objects between the processes, but they only support pickleable objects right?

I also thought of adding C code to my python that:

- create at thread
- parsing the file
- replaces the internal Tree object with the newly created one.

But I wanted to avoid this "hacky" way.

Comment: Are you able to init that unpickleables inside Thread instead on the Main code? Maybe send to Thread just the filename

Comment: Yes I can init the unpickleables on the remote process, but I still need to send back the response (in my case the resulted Tree object) to the main thread. which return to the original problem, communicate unpickleable between processses.